# LiveData null after deleting item

Tags: android, android-room, android-architecture-components, android-livedata

I have LiveData object that I perform a Transformations.map() on to apply a formula to the data before notifying any observers. However I have a delete function on the UI that deletes the object from the DB (room) and when the LiveData gets updated, the Transformation.map() causes a crash with the following error "Attempt to invoke virtual method 'double java.lang.Double.doubleValue()' on a null object reference" since the object it was observing has been removed from the DB

I have tried also removing the observer after the first update but it is still throwing the same error.

I've posted the code below, anyone have any ideas to solve it?

```
    public LiveData<String> getTotalValue() {
    if (totalValueLiveData == null) {
        loadTotalValue();
    }
    totalValue = Transformations.map(totalvalueLiveData, total -> String.format(Locale.getDefault(), "%.1f", UtilUserUnitsConverter.convertValue(total, userUnit)));
    return totalValue;
}

    final Observer<String> getTotalValueObserver = new Observer<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onChanged(@Nullable String totalValue) {
            if (totalValue != null) {
                totalValueTv.setText(totalValue);
            }
    viewModel.getTotalValue().removeObserver(getTotalValueObserver);
        }
    };
    viewModel.getTotalValue().observe(this, getTotalValueObserver);
```

Answer (score 0):

It has been 4 months for this question, but the problem is more likely to be from your `viewModel.getTotalValue()` method.

`Transformations.map()` method creates a new LiveData object each time you call it, which means, each time to call `viewModel.getTotalValue()` you get a whole new object.

In other terms: you call `removeObserver` and `observe` on two different objects without noticing.